# Is there a 3rd party program that can change the cursor size?

Tags: macos, mouse, system-settings, accessibility

I've always used a larger mouse icon in Windows (made it easier to find when zipping around multiple screens :p). Recently switched to using OSX and discovered that the option to enlarge the mouse icon does just that, literally.

It just zooms the mouse up... Normally this wouldnt be an issue, except when I use photoshop, the icons are all larger than their effect area (ie, brush size is inaccurate) due to the mouse literally being scaled up.

Is there another application that can **replace** the system mouse rather than just scaling it up??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Occassionally I use [Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/) when giving demos to help the audience track my mouse movements. Mouse Locator doesn't increase the size of the mouse pointer per say, instead it "paints a target" around the pointer when you start moving the mouse. The target makes it easier to locate the pointer location. [Omnidazzle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle/) also does this, but the effects are flashier.

Comment: thanks, its not ideal, but better than nothing!

Answer (score 3):

If you open System Preferences>Universal Access>Mouse & Trackpad, you can adjust the cursor size to be larger. To my knowledge, there is no third party application that will do this since it is allowed natively. Hope this helps!

Comment: ... as I said, I've found the feature to scale up the cursor, but its not ideal (it literally zooms it up, the beachball looks all pixelated when it spins)

Comment: The cursor is no longer pixellated in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Yolo mouse, It can change both size and color you are also able to change on the fly.  You can also import different styles and use them ans well in small medium and large.